# only show some data of array on ajax return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Is there a way to only show [reason] from the array and not everything inside data? somebody said that I need to use JSON but I tried `contentType: "application/json"` with stringify() but then `success: function(data)` returns my whole HTML instead of the array.

My question is how can I show only [reason] in `$('#testajax').html(data);` instead of everything inside data?
[image: console.log]console.log

*script.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var date = "";
var begin = "";
var tijdsduur = "";
var aantal = "";


$('#datum').change(function() {
  date = $("#datum").val();
  console.log(date);
});
$('#beginTijd').change(function(){
    begin =( $(this).val() ); 
    console.log(begin);      
});
$('#Tijdsduur').change(function(){
    tijdsduur =( $(this).val() ); 
    console.log(tijdsduur);      
});
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
aantal = ($(this).val());
console.log(aantal);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      data: {
          date: date,
          begin: begin,
          eind: tijdsduur,
          quantity: aantal
      },
      success: function(data) {
          $('#testajax').html(data);
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
});
});
```

**UPDATED** *index.php*

```
        <?php
    $date = "";
    $begin = "";
    $tijdsduur = "";
    $aantal = "";
    if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
      if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "Yes, mail is set";
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $begin = $_POST['begin'];
            $tijdsduur = $_POST['eind'];
            $aantal = $_POST['quantity'];
            $eind = $begin + $tijdsduur;
            $startTijd = "$date " . $begin;
            $eindTijd = "$date " . $eind . ":00";
            echo $date . "<br>";
            echo "$startTijd". "<br>";
            echo "$eindTijd". "<br>";
            echo $aantal. "<br>";
            $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
                    $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
                    $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
                    $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
                    echo "$cleancanmakereservation";
                    echo json_encode($reservationAvailable);
        }
        else {
            echo "No, mail is not set";
      }
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

[image: console.log]
console.log(date[0].reason);

[image: console.log]
console.log(date);

Comment: in your success try JSON.parse(data);
then $('#testajax').html(data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return data in `json_encode` from your `index.php`

Then in your ajax success function just get it by

```
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.reason); //if its comming then add it to your html.
      $('#testajax').html(data.reason);
  }
```

Comment: this is the good image when I `echo json_encode($reservationAvailable);` https://imagebin.ca/v/3wYVuvIw7tg4.